# PowerShell Transcript errors when transcript is already running

Tags: powershell

In a PowerShell script I want to make a transcript of whatever the script is doing with `Start-Transcript`. However, sometimes the script failed, and a transcript is already running. In that case an error is thrown and I can't find a way to avoid that error. **What can I do to fail-safe start a transcript?**

If the transcript is already running I would like to simply stop it and start a new one.

The error can be reproduced by intentionally start two transcripts. Remember that in real life a previous run of the script has left the transcript open.

**The error situation**

```
PS C:\> Start-Transcript c:\test.txt # pretend that this is a transcript which was not stopped properly by a previous script

Transcript started, output file is c:\test.txt

PS C:\> Start-Transcript c:\test.txt
Start-Transcript : Transcription cannot be started.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Transcript c:\test.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Transcript], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotStartTranscription,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartTranscriptCommand
```

**Ignoring the with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` does not work!**

```
PS C:\> Start-Transcript c:\test.txt # pretend that this is a transcript which was not stopped properly by a previous script
Transcript started, output file is c:\test.txt

PS C:\> Start-Transcript c:\test.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-Transcript : Transcription cannot be started.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Transcript c:\test.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Transcript], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotStartTranscription,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartTranscriptCommand
```

**Stopping the transcript before starting it fails if the transcript was not running**

```
PS C:\> Start-Transcript c:\test.txt
Transcript started, output file is c:\test.txt

PS C:\> Stop-Transcript  # pretend that this is a transcript which was not stopped properly by a previous script
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\test.txt

PS C:\> Stop-Transcript
Stop-Transcript : An error occurred stopping transcription: The host is not currently transcribing.
At line:1 char:1
+ Stop-Transcript
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Stop-Transcript], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopTranscriptCommand
```

Answer (score 2):

So, all my testing on PS 5.0 (Which is the only one I have access to at the moment) revealed that starting a transcript again with the same output file name would throw the error you mentioned but also stops the transcript. Manually trying to stop it afterwards would tell me that the `The host is not currently transcribing`.

So, I think you can use the try catch method to suppress the error:

```
Try{Start-transcript C:\transcript.txt -ErrorAction Stop}catch{Start-Transcript C:\transcript.txt}
```